# How to use nested json data in hive/shared_preference or any other in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to store a nested json data . In which each json object can be added/deleted by the user.
Something like this:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "folders": [
        {
          "folders": [
            {
              "folders": [],
              "links": []
            }
          ],
          "links": []
        },
        {
          "folders": [],
          "links": []
        }
      ],
      "links": []
    },
    {
      "folders": [],
      "links": []
    },
    {
      "folders": [],
      "links": []
    }
  ],
  "links": []
}
```

Like this in which each folders can be added or deleted by the user. One solution I found on internet is to use this json data as string by encoding it and store it in database(hive). I want to find a better solution if any?

Answer (score 0):

For save data in sharedpreferences:

```
static void setJsonData(String? json) {
    _sharedPreferences?.setString('jsonData', json ?? '');
}
```

For fetch data from sharedpreferences:

```
static String? get getJsonData => _sharedPreferences?.getString('jsonData');
```

after getting this data, do parsing!

Enjoy!

Comment: You are not getting what I am asking @Pradip D

Comment: Please, correct me if I'm wrong, Explain me brief. Above answer is for store and retrieve your data in local storage! @SatendraPal